# weblogic 12c - versioned application access by ALLOW_EXTERNAL_APP_LOOKUP true not works

Tags: java, environment-variables, weblogic, jndi

I am trying to access a versioned application EJB remote lookup from client side also versioned.

but I got:

```
####<Dec 3, 2017, 4:06:36,267 PM AEDT> <Warning> <JNDI> <macdev.tweedheadstorage.com.au> <OzsscEJBServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '20' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' for workmanager: null@null@weblogic.kernel.System> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-01242AED82D5> <26bc5a01-6653-4fec-9d85-75a7ca35e240-0000714f> <1512277596267> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-050006> <An attempt was made to look up the versioned object "java:global.OzsscEJB.EJB.EmailFacadeEJB" from an external client or another application. This can potentially cause in-flight work of the application version not being tracked properly, and thus, be retired prematurely.>
```

BEA-0500006 error thrown, cause server object "retired prematurely". based on oracle exception information:

BEA-050006: Warning: An attempt was made to look up versioned object "name" from an external client or another application. This can potentially cause in-flight work of the application version not being tracked properly and thus being retired prematurely.
Description
An attempt was made to look up versioned object "name" from an external client or another application. This can potentially cause in-flight work of the application version not being tracked properly and thus being retired prematurely.
Cause
An attempt was made to look up versioned object "name" from an external client or another application. This can potentially cause in-flight work of the application version not being tracked properly and thus being retired prematurely.
Action
Please make sure that the possibility of premature retirement of the application version is either tolerated or handled properly. To disable this check, users can set the JNDI environment property as specified by weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ALLOW_EXTERNAL_LOOKUP to "true" when performing lookup of the versioned object.

I setup JNDI environment property in my client side lookup process as:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Environment env = new Environment();
    try{
        prop.load(((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/ozssc-clustered-ejb.properties"));
        env.setInitialContextFactory(prop.getProperty("java.naming.factory.initial"));
        env.setProviderUrl(prop.getProperty("java.naming.provider.url"));
        env.setSecurityPrincipal(prop.getProperty("java.naming.security.principal"));
        env.setSecurityCredentials(prop.getProperty("java.naming.security.credentials"));
        env.setProperty("weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ALLOW_EXTERNAL_LOOKUP",true);
        env.setProperty("weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ALLOW_GLOBAL_RESOURCE_LOOKUP",true);
        /*logger.info("Property file loaded.");*/
        Context ctx = env.getInitialContext();
        if (ctx !=null){
            return ctx;
        }else
            return null;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Rebuild and redeployment applications to web logic server. it is still not works.

BEA-050006 error still throws.

I am very confused as, in my understanding, allow external lookup is server side property for a JNDI object, why oracle said "users can set the JNDI environment property as specified by weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ALLOW_EXTERNAL_LOOKUP to "true" when performing lookup of the versioned object."?

And there is no way to set up a JNDI environment property in server side at all, is it? If some one have such experience, please share to me.

Answer (score 1):

weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ALLOW_EXTERNAL_APP_LOOKUP is not a property name but a constant of the WebLogic API.

Take a look at the [API Reference of Interface WLContext](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/jndi/WLContext.html#ALLOW_EXTERNAL_APP_LOOKUP)

Use the field value to set the property:

```
env.put("weblogic.jndi.allowExternalAppLookup", "true");
```

But this only disables the BEA-050006 warnings and does not solve any problems or errors in this context.